# SublimeText2 - Wrap lines with quotes or tags skipping initial whitespaces

Tags: sublimetext2

I know i can select a block of lines, and then split it into many selections, one per line, using Ctrl+Shift+L then just typing a quote it will wrap the line automatically or to wrap each line with htlm tags I know I can use ctrl+shift+w 
The problem is that I would like to skip the initial whitespaces of each line and just adding a quote or a html tag at the begging of the first word. 
ps: Im using SublimeText 2 with Vintage

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Select a block, then press:

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+End</kbd>

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Exactly! I just missed the home button =/ Just another solution with vintage: Shift+Alt+Down to add next line, hit '^' to the first non-white character than hit 'v' to enter visual mode and than hit $ to the end of each line. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Select a block, then press:

Command+Shift+L, right-arrow, Command+Shift+left-arrow

(Note: I'm on a mac.)